# Deploying ROS solution without source

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best practice approach to transfer my ROS solution: c++-based nodes, python-based nodes, launch files, config files, ...  to a target platform, excluding the source code?

Which folders from my own catkin workspace are needed?

And is there any way to find the minimal ROS package set, I need to install on the target?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264744/deploying-ros-solution-without-source/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-06-26**:
Ahhh, I now found a snap package tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Packaging%20your%20ROS%20project%20as%20a%20snap
Looks like worth having a look at. But I will leave the question open a little while, your comments are still appreciated.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-26**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/192419/how-to-setup-bloom-to-generate-a-local-deb-outside-of-rosorg-buildfarm/ also mentions the tarring up of the catkin_ws/install dir after a catkin_make install which is easiest.  The local deb building method may be easier now than when documented in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own - now old - question: the catkin_ws install dir seems to hold everything if the CMakelists files have proper definitions on what to install.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2018-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/43908/sdyy/) on 2020-11-19**:
But target device still need to install ROS core, and all dependent library. Just move install folder may not be run.